# Связать pm2 и express

Tags: node.js, сервер, администрирование, express, npm

Когда запускаю через DEBUG=myapp:* npm start - все работает. Pm2 работает только с одной страничкой и не видит модули require в скрипте.

```
//пробовал и так
pm2 start /var/www/html/myapp
//и так
pm2 start /var/www/html/myapp/app.js
//и так
pm2 start /var/www/html/procesess.json
```

Ничего не работает.

Comment: pm2 start "npm start"

Answer (score 0):

Помогла статья [node+pm2+express+ngnix](http://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-deploy-nodejs-applications-with-pm2-and-nginx-on-ubuntu/)

Это как-то связано с потерявшей совместимостью express к Pm2.

```
pm2 start app.js //больше не работает
```

Нужно искать точку входа в приложение в package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
},
```

И запускать pm2 так, находясь в директории приложения и в не-рут юзере:

```
pm2 start ./bin/www
```

После этого обязательно выйти из нерутовского юзера. И под рутом запустить:

```
pm2 startup ubuntu
```

Вот такая магия.